# How to create a dynamic table view I want to know

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

![enter image description here][1]I want to display a section the button is pressed. and,I want to display the current time on the section title. and,One cell is displayed section is displayed.
Date the button was pressed at the same time, the section title is I do not want a two.
I made ​​a static TableView first.
I tried to make this purpose, a dynamic TableView then while reading the various sites. Code is commented out it.
Please tell me a sample of the code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
    //return [array count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *title = @"section";
    return title;

    //return [array objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i", @"row", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)addButton
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    NSString *strTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
     [array addObject:strTime];
    [array count];
}
```

Comment: Sorry.The answer I may be slow because it already midnight.

Comment: I'm sorry. But your question is not very well written. It is hard to understand what you want to know. Plus, if it is midnight, I am guessing you don't live in the US, which might be why your English is not great. Either way, I would suggest re-writing your question in a more clear and concise way.

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words, if you could draw a simple wireframe of what you are trying to do it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are planning to achieve here. Assuming that you want to display the time when add button is pressed and to show that in the section title of your table view. The code will look like this,

Declare an @property to hold the date in this current class .h file,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateString;
```

In add button action,

```
-(void)addButton
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; //set the date format appropriately, Check SO for sample date formats.

    self.dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [self.tableView reloadData];//reload your table view to show this date in title
}
```

Your section title delegate method will look like,

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return self.dateString;//modify this as per your requirement
    else 
        return @"title";
}
```

Tweak the above code to suit your requirement.